# Japanese equivalent of "I identify as X"

Tags: translation, word-choice, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a way to express the feeling that sometimes comes up when the way you feel about yourself contrasts with surface-level observations about you. In English we have the "identify as" construct e.g.

"I was born in France, but I identify as American."

You can replace "I identify as X" above with "In my heart, I am X". The closest thing I could find in Jisho was:

「自分が別人になった感じだ。」

Using that I did my best to translate the sentence above as:

「私はフランスで生まれだけど、自分がアメリカ人感じだ。」

"I was born in France, but I myself feel like an American."

Is this accurate, and if not, what would be the best way to express this type of sentence in Japanese?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two possible expressions you can use (After the "I was born in France" part):

```
(私は)もうすっかりアメリカ人になっています。

(私は）自分の事をアメリカ人だと思っています。
```

I think if you modified your above attempt to say "自分がアメリカ人みたいな感じ", it would be a little more natural.

Comment: Yeah, I also would say 「フランス生まれですが、/ 生まれはフランスですが、自分のことを / 自分をアメリカ人だと思っています。」 By the way, did you notice the typo (or error?) in the OP: 私はフランス**で**生まれ**だ**けど ? (And.. I think もうすっかりアメリカ人です might sound more natural..)

Comment: @chocolate what would be the fix to the typo/error? Would it be 「私はフランスで生まれ**た*けど」?

Comment: @Hamsteriffic Yes, it would be フランス**で**生まれたけど or フランス生まれ**だ**けど.

Comment: @chocolate: Good point about the です vs になってる, I agree.

Answer (score 4):

Here's some other variants:

フランス生まれだけど、心は日本人。
I was born in France, but my heart is Japanese.

カナダ人ですけど、考え方はフランス人。
I am Canadian but I think like a French person.

マレーシア生まれの中国人ですけど、長い間ドイツで仕事したので、感覚はドイツ人かもしれないです。
I am a Malaysian-born Chinese but because I have worked in Germany for a long time, my sense (way of thinking) is likely German.

アメリカで生まれたが、カナダの価値観を持ってます。
I was born in America, but I have Canadian values.

Comment: `カナダの価値観持ってます` ->  Did you leave out 「を」 intentionally or accidentally?

Comment: @chocolate accidentally :P.

Answer (score 3):

You can say 「私は**フランス生まれだ**けど、」 ("Though I **am French-born**," ) or 「私は**フランスで生まれた**けど、」("Though I **was born in France**,") but not 「私はフランスで生まれだけど、」 ("Though I'm in France born,"(?)).

Tweaking your translation (minimally), we may come up with:

> 私は[フランス生まれだ/フランスで生まれた]けど、自分がアメリカ人[のような/みたいな]感じだ。

Or you could say something like:

> (私は)生まれはフランス人ですが、心はアメリカ人です。 (I am a Frenchman/Frenchwoman by birth but an American at heart.)

There are myriad ways to express it, really, especially the latter half.

Answer (score 3):

I think the most widely applicable phrase might be:

> 自分のことを **X** だと考えている

- 自分のことを**日本人**だと考えています
  I identify as **Japanese**  （国籍）
- 自分のことを**プログラマー**だと考えています
  I identify as **a programmer**  （職業）
- 自分のことを**阪神のファン**だと考えています
  I identify as **a Hanshin fan**  （団体所属）

This is very similar to saying "I think of myself as X", which I think is basically equivalent to "I identify as X".

In contrast to fact:

> 私はフランス生まれですが、自分のことをアメリカ人だと**考えています**。
>   私はフランス生まれですが、自分のことをアメリカ人だと**感じています**。

- Using 考える as above sounds like perceive yourself as American rather than French
- Using 感じる as above sounds like you realize that you are French, but you *feel* American